# Mail alert for specific tags

Tags: support, tags, notifications

I want to monitor a specific tag and would like to be informed when question with that tag arises.

I know I can create an RSS/Atom feed based on a tag.

But I need it as email. Is it possible?

Comment: Mobile now, can answer properly later if no one else does, but https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/19177/revisions indicates that the email feature was recently removed

Comment: Than I can I (as an upstream maintainer) monitor the tag of my own application?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the email piece was recently removed from the ["How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) Help Center page. One of its links is to the ["What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/307535) page on Meta Stack Exchange, whose answer was edited on August 18th to add:

> You can no longer choose to receive emails about new activity within a tag.

As of today, I believe you can still get emails via your network account. I think the steps are:

1. Visit https://stackexchange.com/filters/, which will redirect to https://stackexchange.com/filters/(your network account id)/my-filter
2. Click the "New filter" button, if that page doesn't already come up.
3. Toggle section #1 to select just the tag you're interested in.
4. Still in section #1, choose "All sites" or a particular list of sites.
5. Click "Add rule".
6. Name the filter in section #2.
7. Importantly for you, enter your email address in section #3, tick the box for "Yes send email", and select the frequency you want.
8. Preview and/or Save the Changes.

While searching Meta Stack Exchange for this issue, I found several posts where emails stopped working for one reason or another. Given the August 18th change, I'm uncertain whether Stack Exchange will continue supporting the network profile-based email subscriptions, but the one I have is still working.

Comment: Same here, my email alerts are still working.